# Isn't there something wrong in this sentence? Does 対抗できずに create semantic conflict?

Tags: translation

I´m reading [this article](http://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/110000208692) and the sentence below looks weird to me. I copied it as it is in this article:

> 拒否しよう**と**決心した気持ちに**対抗できずに**、言われるままに行動してしまう主人公の姿は、現代人の中にも根強く生きていると感じる。

There are some parts which I struggle with.

> 拒否しよう**と**決心した気持ちに**対抗できずに**

I have trouble understanding the meanings of と and 対抗できずに.
This seems illogical to me.
What do you think about it?

Comment: For できずに see http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21727/ず-negative-verb
And then the と indicates, so it looks like in this sentence to me, that the following 「決心した気持ちに」 is a logical consequence of 拒否しよう.

Comment: う～ん？？おかしいよね・・・「『拒否しよう』と決心した気持ち**を貫き通せずに**、言われるままに行動してしまう」とかであるべきでは・・・？

Comment: Could you tell us what the sentence is from and maybe double-check that you've typed it correctly?  Everyone seems to be confused.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.
I edited my question and copied the link where you can download the article in which I found this sentence.
I typed it as it is written there. I doubled checked with a friend and we are both confused about it...

Answer (score 6):

> 「拒否しよう」と決心した気持ちに対抗できずに
>   unable to beat/resist his/her (own) resolution to say no

- 「拒否しよう」>> "I will refuse" "I won't obey" "I'll say no"
- と >> the case particle as a quotative marker
- 決心した気持ち >> determined mind, decision, resolution
- に対抗できずに ≒ に対抗できなくて/できないで >> "Not being able to beat/resist..." "Unable to beat/resist..."

---

Edit:

私には、「拒否しようと決心した気持ちに対抗できず」と「言われるままに行動してしまう」が、互いに相反する内容に思われて、なぜここで「対抗できず」という言葉が使われているか分かりません。どなたかお分かりになる方、ご回答くださいませんか。

---

Update: I confirmed this with a Japanese language teacher so here's how I read it:

As you can see, this is logically incompatible with the 言われるままに行動してしまう part. I think the writer meant to write something like 拒否しようと決心した気持ちを[貫]{つらぬ}き通せずに、言われるままに行動してしまう主人公 (The hero, who ends up doing as he is told, unable to act up to his resolution to say no), but chose the wrong word 対抗 for some reason.

Comment: Agreed that the sentence contradicts itself.